# PDO Update User Information Query

Tags: php, pdo, session-variables

its me again :)
i'm almost done with my project theres only one more thing left.
i am not able to update values in my database using pdo.
this is my script

```
<a 
href="?UpdateUser=' .$ID. '" 
class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row"
data-original-title="Bearbeiten" 
ref="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditUser">
<i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="EditUser" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="EditUserModal"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                   <div class="modal-dialog modal-simple modal-center">
                     <form class="modal-content" method="POST" role="form" action="">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                           <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                         </button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="EditUserModal">Benutzer bearbeiten</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xl-12 form-group">
                           <p><b>Username</b></p>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="'.$username.'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xl-4 form-group">
                              <p><b>Vorname</b></p>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vorname" value="'.$vorname.'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xl-8 form-group">
                           <p><b>Nachname</b></p>
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nachname" value="'.$nachname.'">
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-xl-8 form-group">
                         <p><b>Email</b></p>
                             <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="'.$email.'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xl-4 form-group">
                           <p><b>TelefonNr.</b></p>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="handy" value="'.$handy.'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-xl-12 form-group">
                           <p><b>Admin</b></p>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin" value="'.$admin.'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12 float-right">
                             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit">Speichern</button>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </form>
                   </div>
                 </div>
            </td>
                            </tr>';
           }
           if(isset($_POST['UpdateUser']))
           {
               if($_POST['UpdateUser'])
               {
                 $stmt = $odb->execute("UPDATE Account SET username = '$username' , vorname = '$vorname', nachname = '$nachname', email = '$email', handy = '$handy', admin = '$admin' WHERE id=? ");
                 }
                 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh()' content='0'>";
           }
```

am i doing a wrong query ? or why is it not updating?
there is no error showing up on the page, but the values are not updating nor refreshing the page.

Comment: `WHERE id=?` Where are you binding the variable for this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard im not sure, im not that familiar with all of that :/ if followed instructions and guides to get along

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `prepare` before `execute`, like this:

```
$query = 'UPDATE Account SET 
          username = :username,
          vorname  = :vorname,
          nachname = :nachname,
          email    = :email,
          handy    = :handy,
          admin    = :admin
          WHERE id = :id';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute(array(
       ':username' => $username,
       ':vorname'  => $vorname,
       ':nachname' => $nachname,
       ':email'    => $email,
       ':handy'    => $handy,
       ':admin'    => $admin,
       ':id'       => $id
));
```

Also, is better to use placeholders for every input value, instead of write variables inside the query string.

And now I figured out this:

You are using a form to send data with method POST and trying to read `$_POST['UpdateUser']` to start executing the update, but in that form there is no field called `UpdateUser`.
You have to add that value inside the form, or change the `if (isset($_POST['UpdateUser']))` with some other field.

Comment: tried it, your solution looks really clean, i should try to stick to that structure in future, but it didnt worked tho, still same thing happening [here](https://gyazo.com/6e982c2aca2fff2eb72e7f307e4d6d72)

Comment: can you post the entire code? it seems like something is missing at the beginning

Comment: Check this, again again: in my answer I used `$pdo`, but you have `$odb`. May be you didnt change that?

Comment: i did and its still not working , what else could it be ? maybe the $_POST ?